# macvim Color Scheme Pencil deactivates displaying Line Numbers

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, macos-catalina, color-scheme

Am running macvim 8.2.319 on macOS Catalina (10.15.4)...

Inside /home/myuser/.gvimrc:

```
set nu!

syntax on

if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Inconsolata\ 12
  elseif has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=JetBrains\ Mono\ Regular:h14
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI
  endif
endif

colorscheme pencil

set background=light
let g:airline_theme = 'pencil'
```

Downloaded the pencil color scheme from:

https://github.com/reedes/vim-colors-pencil/blob/master/colors/pencil.vim

Download and placed it inside this directory:

```
~/.vimrc/colors
```

Before setting the color scheme inside .gvimrc file by issuing this:

`colorschme pencil`, the line numbers would show up

now when I launched Terminal and typed in:

```
gvim hello.py
```

Now it seems to turn off the `set nu!` which is inside the first line of my .gvimrc file.

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Set number! toggles the option value. Try set number

Comment: Still didn't work... Before I tried to use the pencil colorscheme ```set nu!``` would work and after I launch gvim (using the pencil colorscheme) it only works if I manually set it using Escape and then ```:set nu!```

Comment: Well, ive glanced at the code and it doesnt turn off number. Please try without the exclamation point

Comment: Yes, that  (```set nu```) worked, thank you!